# Most Performant Way to Convert DateTime to Int Format

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

I need to convert Datetime fields to a specifically formatted INT type. For example, I want 
 `2000-01-01 00:00:00.000` to convert to `20010101`.

What is the most performant way to make that conversion for comparison in a query?

Something like:

```
DATEPART(year, orderdate) * 10000 + DATEPART(month, orderdate) * 100 + 
    DATEPART(day, orderdate)
```

or

```
cast(convert(char(8), orderdate, 112) as int)
```

What's the most performant way to do this?

Comment: Simple answer: test both and see which is "better" (e.g. quicker, uses less CPU, uses less reads/writes, etc)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your example of `cast(convert(char(8), orderdate, 112) as int)` seems fine to me.  It quickly gets the date down to the format you need and converted to an int.

From an execution plan standpoint, there seems to be no difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with TSQL builtin functions. 
It's not .NET tick compatible but it's still FAST sortable and you can pick your GRANULARITY on demand:

```sql
SELECT setup.DateToINT(GETDATE(),  4) -- will output 2019 for 2019-06-06 12:00.456 
SELECT setup.DateToINT(GETDATE(),  6) -- will output 201906 for 2019-06-06 12:00.456 
SELECT setup.DateToINT(GETDATE(), 20) -- will output 20190606120045660 for 2019-05-05 12:00.456     

CREATE FUNCTION setup.DateToINT(@datetime DATETIME, @length int) 
       RETURNS 
       BIGINT WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
BEGIN 
       RETURN CONVERT(BIGINT,
                      SUBSTRING(
                        REPLACE(REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(REPLACE(
                                CONVERT(CHAR(25), GETDATE(), 121)
                        ,'-','')
                        ,':','')
                        ,' ','')
                        ,'.','')
                    ,0
                    ,@length+1)
                    )
END
GO
```

Answer (score -2):

Is this what you need

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),'2010-01-01 00:00:00.000',101),'-','')
```

Comment: That's a lot more work than `cast(convert(char(8), orderdate, 112) as int)`, which will work just as well.  Your example doesn't even take converting to an INT into account.

Answer (score -3):

When you pass '2010-01-01 00:00:00.000' directly in your code, the SELECT statement looks at it as a string and not a datetime data type. Its not the same as selecting a datetime field directly.

There is no need to do outer CAST because SQL Server will do implicit conversion, here is a proof.

```
DECLARE @t DATETIME = '2010-01-10 00:00:00.000',@u INT
SELECT @u = CONVERT(CHAR(8), @t, 112)

IF ISNUMERIC(@u) = 1
PRINT 'Integer'
```

Comment: Maybe what you refer to is this `SELECT CONVERT(INT, CAST ('2013-08-05 09:23:30' as DATETIME))` comes from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) the conversion is **implicit**